# RxJs Observable from backed with pulling

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm quite new to RxJs (and not that good in js ) and have a hard time finding how I can write Rx equivalent of

```
var arr = [];

var getData = function () {
    $.get("/newlines", {}, function (data) {
        data.push.apply(arr, data);
        setTimeout(getData, 1000);
        console.log(arr);

    },'json');

};

setTimeout(getData, 1000);
```

What I'm thinking about is to Observable which will produce items from async callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
    .selectMany(Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.get("/newlines", {})))
    .subscribe(function(data) {        
        data.push.apply(arr, data);
        console.log(arr);
});
```

Typed on my Smartphone thus untested.